# Kendo generated dropdown box set open as disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have an asp.net MVC application which uses kendo to generate a dropdown box.  This is the code that is executing:

```
<div id="suffixDiv">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4">
        <label class="tax-label">Suffix</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3  col-sm-2">
        @(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
         .Name("ddlFrm")
         .DataTextField("Suffix")
         .DataValueField("Suffix")
         .DataSource(source =>
         {
             source.Read(read =>
             {
                 read.Action("GetFileSuffix", "Home");
                 read.Type(HttpVerbs.Post);
             })
             .ServerFiltering(true); //If true, the DataSource will not filter the data on the client.
         })
         .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:60px;" })
         )
     </div>
 </div>
```

This code ends up generating a doropdown box with the following values:
{blank}
A
B
C
D

There is another field on the view that has a value from 0 - 9.  When this field has a value of 8, I need to have the {blank} value of the dropdown disabled.  When the value of the field is any other value, I need to have the {blank} enabled.

When I inspect the dropdown, and look at the elements, I dont see an element called ddlFrm.  It looks like it got re-named ddlFrm_input when the html got rendered.

When I put this code in the document ready section

```
var mySelect = $('#ddlFrmAuth_input');
var selectedText = mySelect.find(':selected').text();
var selectedValue = mySelect.find(':selected').val();
alert(selectedText + "/" + selectedValue);
```

The alert states " / undefined".

So obviously, if I try to execute this code:

```
if (selectedValue == "8")
{
    $("#ddlFrm_input option[value=' ']").prop("disabled", true);
}
```

nothing happens.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Couple important points here:

- `ddlForm_input` is not your *select* in that case. Kendo generates a hidden `input` to hold the widget's value and wraps it in a fancy looking `ul` to be able to style it better than native `select`;
- As said above, the generated structure is an `ul` list, so there are no `option` elements on it.

I believe disabling an option is not a feature in that widget. So you need to handle it by yourself. I will give a blind shot here as I don't have a .net environment to test, but I will try:

- Create a [`Template`](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/api/Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent/ComboBoxBuilder#templatesystemstring) to make the item look like its disable like this:

  ```
  .Template("# if (data.disabled) { <span class='text-decoration: line-through;'>##= data.Suffix ##</span> } else { ##= data.Suffix ## } #")
  ```

  Note: Use whatever styles you need in that `span` to show user that the option is disabled, like some grayed text for example.
- The item is still selectable, so you need to prevent it's selection. Add a javascript event to the widget:

  ```
  $('#ddlForm').data('kendoComboBox').bind('select',  function(e) {
      if (e.item.disabled) {
          e.preventDefault();
          return false;
      }
  });
  ```

  That event will work as this [demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/@marcio/iJuQEfuv).
- Now when you need to disable any item, just set the `disabled` option in ComboBox's dataSource:

  ```
  $('#ddlForm').data('kendoComboBox').dataSource.at(0).disabled = true;
  // Or
  $('#ddlForm').data('kendoComboBox').dataSource.at(0).set('disabled', true);
  ```

Give it a try. It should work.